# "NULL identity key" error using SQLAlchemy's base automap to reflect a postgres DB using IDENTITY columns

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a postgres database that I'm trying to reflect that uses the now standard "Identity" column for primary keys.

Here's my table definition:

```sql
create table class_label (
    class_label_id integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    class_name varchar not null,
    default_color varchar,
    created_dttm timestamp default current_timestamp NOT NULL,
    created_by varchar DEFAULT USER NOT NULL,
    updated_dttm timestamp default current_timestamp NOT NULL,
    updated_by varchar DEFAULT user NOT NULL
);
```

And here's my code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, insert, Table, or_, and_, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
import os

from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateColumn
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

@compiles(CreateColumn, 'postgresql')
def use_identity(element, compiler, **kw):
    text = compiler.visit_create_column(element, **kw)
    text = text.replace("SERIAL", "INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY")
    return text

usr = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_USR")
pwd = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PWD")
host = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_HOST")

engine = create_engine('postgresql://' + usr + ':' + pwd + host, convert_unicode=True)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

metadata.reflect(engine, only=['class_label'])
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()

Class_Label = Base.classes.class_label

session.add(Class_Label(class_name="Testing", default_color="red"))
session.commit()
```

When I run my code, I get this error:

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Instance <class_label at 0x1091c4ba8> has a NULL identity key.
>   If this is an auto-generated value, check that the database table allows generation of new
>   primary key values, and that the mapped Column object is configured to expect these generated
>   values.  Ensure also that this flush() is not occurring at an inappropriate time, such as within
>   a load() event.

Per https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-10-identity-columns I understand that this is somewhat a shortcoming of SQLAlchemy, but I'm wondering if the work-around they suggest can work for auto-mapped/reflected databases and how I would implement it.

I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.3.16 and Postgres 11.

Comment: This is currently being addressed [on GitHub](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5324).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix was added in [SQLAlchemy 1.4](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_14.html#change-36ba10688af2cf9bc6b46cc83df64f99)